# Do Vulcans have any colonies outside of their home system?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Have the Vulcans established any colonies outside of their home system, as the humans and other Federation species have? If yes, what are they? If no, why not?

This is especially relevant for the Kelvin timeline given that the planet Vulcan was destroyed, and their species would have a much better chance of surviving if there were colonies on other worlds or space stations.

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_colonies

Answer (score 10):

One of the early plot lines in Star Trek Enterprise deals with a Vulcan monastery called P'Jem which is located in a system near Andoria according to [memory alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/P%27Jem), so this is a colony (or at least a settlement) outside of the Vulcan system.